# Https connection - using public key approach for secure connections

Tags: android, ios, ssl-certificate, public-key, root-certificate

I'm using public pinning key approach for secure connection in app (android and iOS).
As of now we're using public key approach where public key used in app having leaf certificate's key, you can refer to https://mailapurvpandey.medium.com/ssl-pinning-in-android-90dddfa3e051

Problem which we're seeing that every time server certificate rotates, we must have to re-spin app as well with new public key certificate baked in app.

Is it possible if we could use root certificate's public keys in app side for ssl certificate trust?